# Output a value outside a slider change function

Tags: c#

I have the following code where I would like to access the variable values from this slider function to the constructor as shown below

```
private void Slider_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
{
    var values = Slider1.Value;
    // value1.Text = values.ToString();
}
```

this is my constructor

```
public DiscoLight()
{
    value1.Text = values.ToString();
}
```

The slider is working inside its function however on the constructor is only outputing a value of zero. Please help solve these.

Comment: Have you added the InitializeComponent() before trying to assign the value? You will need to do so if that constructor is of a form's. Also, is that variable, "values" a public static value?

Comment: It should also be noted that if they (the valuechanged function and the constructor) are both in the same class... it makes little sense. Since the constructor then would be called first, thus even if "values" was a public static variable, it would always be 0, or the value it was instantiated with.